# Exim need to send mail off server

Tags: ubuntu, unix, email-server, sendmail, exim

Never needed to set up a mail server before.

I've got exim up and running perfectly fine. When I send an email using command line to my.email@gmail.com it works wonderfully, arrives from zach@mydomain.com exactly as I'd expect it to.

When I try to send an email TO zach@mydomain.com, though, it doesn't leave the server. It shows up when I type 'mail' and look in there beautifully... but I need it to actually leave so that it can route its way to my Google Apps.

I understand that this "don't leave the server" is the expected behavior... so how do I make it not follow that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out; just getting exim to use the Google Apps MX with a switch in hubbed_hosts.